# Solve problem about voltage drop

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, homework

Can you please help find the voltage drops at 8 Ω and 20 Ω?

Reference below.

[image]

Comment: You could use a simulator to get very accurate results. Have you considered doing that?

Comment: Homework questions need to show an attempt at an answer in order to show us where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Unless you added them yourself, the coloured loop current indicators, I1, I2 & I3, are an indication that you should tackle this exercise using mesh analysis. Presumably you've been covering this in your course. Can you add your attempt at loop equations using the suggested currents to your question?

Answer (score 1):

**A couple of hints**

The first thing I'd do is simplify the interconnections like this: -

[image]

Notice that I've introduced another voltage source but, can you see how things are clearer and easier to simplify a bit more:  -

[image]

Can you see what I've done above? Another simplification: -

[image]

Can you take it from here? Can you convert the new current source and the two parallel resistors to a voltage source?

Comment: please show to get a result please . appreciate your advice.

Comment: You should be able to do this now. The immediate object is the find the voltage on the upper node of the left-side 1.25 amp current source. You should convert the right-side 1.25 amp current source along with 40 ohm and 12 ohm resistors to a voltage source using Thevenin's theorem. Then, using the 8 ohm resistor make a current source with parallel resistors. This new current source combines with the left-side current source to simplify things a bit more.